# First Invoked method in fragment is onDestroy() not onAttach()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-navigation, dagger-hilt

I am using `Navigation component` and `Databinding` and everything is fine but when it comes to fragment lifecycler it's getting a bit wiered. When i'm in a destination(fragment) and navigate to another destination(fragment) the invoked methods are `onAttach: onCreate(), onCreateView(), onViewCreated(), onStart() onResume() onPause() onStop(), onDestroyView()` and when i navigate back surprisingly first method that is invoked is `onDestroy()` and then `onAttach()`.

Here is my codes:

```
//First and second destination are alike
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HistoryFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentHistoryBinding

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach: ")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()")
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ")
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ")
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ")
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: ")
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ")
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    onResumeFunctions()
    isBindingNull = false
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ")
}

private fun onResumeFunctions() {
    onClickListenerFunctions()
}

private fun onClickListenerFunctions() {
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView: ")
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ")
}
```

build.gradle Is :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
id "kotlin-kapt"
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
android {
namespace "***"
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "***"
    minSdk 27
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        // Don't package arm64-v8a or x86_64m
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '18'
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

}

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

//Fragment
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7'

//coroutine
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'


//Dagger-Hilt
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46'
//ksp 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46'


def room_version = "2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
//annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
//kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// Retrofit
def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1"

// OkHttp
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'

//Coil
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2"


//Navigation Component
def nav_version = "2.5.3"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

//RecyclerView
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0"
// For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'


//implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
// Retrofit with Scalar Converter
//implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0"



//Text recognition v1 ML
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'

//Text recognition v2 ML
// To recognize Latin script
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'
// To recognize Chinese script
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-chinese:16.0.0'
// To recognize Devanagari script
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-devanagari:16.0.0'
// To recognize Japanese script
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-japanese:16.0.0'
// To recognize Korean script
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-korean:16.0.0'

//Language identification ML
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:language-id:17.0.4'

//Translation ML
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.1'


//Adivery
implementation 'com.adivery:sdk:4.6.0'

//Leakcanary
//debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.10'

//web scraping
//implementation 'it.skrape:skrapeit:1.2.2'
 }

kapt {
correctErrorTypes true
}
```

And navgraph is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/historyFragment">
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/historyFragment"
    android:name=".features.history.ui.HistoryFragment"
    android:label="fragment_history"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_history">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_historyFragment_to_translationResultFragment"
        app:destination="@id/translationResultFragment"/>
</fragment>
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/savedFragment"
    android:name=".features.saved.ui.SavedFragment"
    android:label="fragment_saved"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_saved" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_saved_to_translationResult"
        app:destination="@id/translationResultFragment" />

</fragment>
```

what is wrong wit my codes ?